# Is it possible to continue downloads from other client?

Tags: windows-7, download, download-manager, continuous-operation

I have downloaded a file using a download-manager. I have change my OS from Windows XP to Windows 7 (download-manager installed). I’ve already tried to continue it. How can I doing download?
Other details:
•   Temporary downloaded file exist.

Comment: Your question seems a bit confusing.  Are you saying you have a dual-boot system, and you want to continue the download after rebooting into the other OS?  If so, I doubt that functionality exists - even if it is theoretically possible at all.

Comment: honestly, is downloading a file again harder than asking a question and waiting for an answer for months?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the same download from the same link to the new download manager.
2. When the new temporary file has been created, pause the download manager.
3. Replace the New Temp file with the Old Temp File.
4. Close and restart the download manager
5. Resume downloading.

The above method has worked with Free Download Manager.

If it's a torrent you're talking about, insert the following step between step 4 and 5:

> Force Recheck (uTorrent Context Menu)

Comment: I'm using DAP(Download Acclerator Plus). But that dos not work.